# Many edges to a single node in graphs in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures

Iam new to c++.I have to write a c++ program representing a graph where the node has many edges as input and single edge as its output.I should also label them.I felt using linked list would help me but i was struck by the thought that in a linked list i would only have a single edge to a given node and another edge going to the next node.Is there any possible way of representing many different edges from different nodes to a single node.

Comment: the question is very brief and "not specific" ... do you have any code !!

Comment: ohh.....I haven't done any coding i just wanted to have an idea as of how i could approach the given problem.

Answer (score 0):

So a node should look something like this:

```
struct Node
{
  Node(std::string label_) : label(label_) {}
  std::string label;
  std::vector<Node*> incoming;
  Node* outgoing = nullptr;
}
```

Then it's just a matter of wiring them together.  Note this is sort of like a linked list of strings, except that the "previous" pointer (`incoming`) is multiple instead of singular.

From here, note that what you are actually building is a tree (assuming one node has a null `outgoing` pointer).  That may help you to find an existing data structure implementation that you can use instead of building your own.

Comment: thanks alot.....i forgot mentioning in the question for suppose among the number of input edges for nodes, some of the edges are same for a given a graph,how would i represent the graph? my task is to represent a graph with many input edges and one output edge which might be input  edge to another node and assign a weight to the edge, i guess assigning weight to a given edge can be done with help of vector easily.I just wanted to have a basic idea to start programming hence i was asking briefly.